# How to write the output of reducer to a database?

Tags: java, database, hadoop, aerospike

I will begin with an example. Suppose the input data is something like

```
User1,product1,time1
User1,product2,time2
User1,product3,time3
User2,product2,time2
User2,product4,time6
```

Now the output which is expected is I have to insert the data to a database(Aerospike(Key Value Store), in my case) where the data should be formatted as

```
User1, [ [product1,time1],[product2,time2],[product3,time3] ]
User2, [ [product2,time2],[product4,time6] ]
```

So In the Mapper I output the below

```
UserID, [productid,timestamp]
```

> Please do not assume that [x,y] means i am outputting list i may send data from mappper in any way may be write the data in a custom object

So at the receiver side I have data in the format

```
User1, [ [product1,time1],[product2,time2],[product3,time3] ]
User2, [ [product2,time2],[product4,time6] ]
```

Now I can do two things

a) I can write the logic to push this data in database in the reducer only
(i dont want to do this)

b) What i want to do is, when we do Context.write() then i want the data to be written to database.

Please help how could this be done and if possible attach a code snippet or pseudo-code

PS : What does Context.write() do ? where does it write to? what are the steps and phases it goes by ?

Comment: context.write writes the data to a file in HDFS or local as mentioned. You could later point an external hive table on this data so that it is available in to query or use hbase to read the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my understanding goes, invoking context.write involves a certain number of steps

In the driver we have to specify the output format. Now lets see what happens if we want to write to a file

For writing to text file we specify something like

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

Now if we see the implementation of the TextOutputFormat class that extends FileOutputFormat(abstract class) which implements the OutputFormat interface and the OutputFormat interface provides two methods

```
1) getRecordWriter
2) checkOutputSpecs
```

Now what will happen, OutputFormatClass just tells what kind of record you want to write and how is given by the record writer, for a record writer it gets just `Object Key, Object Value` where value could be single or a list, and in the implementation of the record writer we specify the actual logic like how should be this record written.

Now Comming back to the original question that how should the record be written to a database in my case Aerospike

I created a custom OutputFormat say

```
public class AerospikeOutputFormat extends OutputFormat {
    //Return a new instance of record writer
    @Override
    public RecordWriter getRecordWriter(TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new AerospikeRecordWriter(context.getConfiguration(), new Progressable() {
        @Override
        public void progress() {

        }
    });
    }

}
```

Now we have to define a custom record writer which would get a key and a value and would write the data to the database

```
public class RSRVRecordWriter<KK,VV> extends RecordWriter<KK, VV> {

    @Override
    public void write(KK key, VV value) throws IOException {
        //Now here we can have an instance of aerospikeclient from a singleton class and then we could do client.put()

    }
```

Above code is just a snippet, proper design strategy must be taken.

PS: Aerospike has given a record writer which could be extended to match your needs at [this link](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-hadoop/blob/master/mapreduce/src/main/java/com/aerospike/hadoop/mapreduce/AerospikeRecordWriter.java)